# Limit to Passing Data with google.script.run?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am trying to pull data from a Google Spreadsheet to populate some divs. However, it is always failing.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert("It is not working")).withSuccessHandler(build_req_view).getRequisitionEntries(); 
});

function build_req_view(things) {
    var list = $('#div-content-req-view-body');
    list.empty();

    for (var x = 1; x < things.length; x++) {
        list.append("<div class=\"req-view-item\">");
        list.append("<div class=\"req-view-item-header\">");
        list.append("REQUISITION NUMBER - STATUS");
        list.append("</div>");

        list.append("</div>");
    }
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="div-content-req-view" class="div-content-container">
  <div id="div-content-req-view-header" class="div-content-header">
    View Requisitions
  </div>

  <div id="div-content-req-view-body" class="div-content-body">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

My Google Apps Script is this:

```
function getRequisitionEntries() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ENTRY).getSheetByName("requisitions").getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

For whatever reason, the `getRequisitionEntries()` function isn't working and thus always prompting the alert. I am confused as to why this isn't working. I have basically used the same HTML, JS, GS code for many other elements in the same project. However, this seems to not run with the `successhandler`.

I was wondering if this was because the data I am trying to pull has more columns than the other SpreadsheetApp calls I use in the project. All the correct IDs are passing correctly as I have checked and double checked.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Where is the javascript with the `google.script.run` function?  Is it in the same file as the HTML, with an html extension?  The `getRequisitionEntries()` function goes in the .gs file which is server side and the rest is in the .html file which is client side.  Or in 2 .html files and you include the one with the javascript.

Comment: The getRequisitionEntries() function is in a .gs file. The HTML and the JavaScript are in two separate files where the JavaScript file is included on the bottom of the HTML file.

Comment: I just didn't add the whole HTML code, just the snippet that the JavaScript is referring to. There are various snippets that basically use the same code but the elements and functions were just renamed to match (i.e. populating a dropdown or a table). Those work in the same project and getRequisitionEntries() is basically a copy and paste but for whatever reason, it isn't working like the other 3.

Comment: On another note, the other snipped contained only strings, but this database contains Timestamps/Dates and links (which should be a string actually now that I think about it).

Comment: Per the [Detailed Documentation of the google.script.run Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#detailed-documentation)  "Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date, Function, DOM element besides a form, or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays."

Answer (score 1):

Per the Detailed Documentation of the google.script.run Class "Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date, Function, DOM element besides a form, or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays." –

Karl_S

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#detailed-documentation

See also this report by Tanaike with bried explanation and more examples:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-values-to-transfer-between-javascript-and-google-apps-script-with-google-script-run-b1420ba16f79

I see 2 options to bypass this:

1. Use Cashe service on backend (data will stay in backend)
2. Use `JSON.stringify`  to convert data to string before passing to front.

Comment: Is this information useful? https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-values-to-transfer-between-javascript-and-google-apps-script-with-google-script-run-b1420ba16f79

Comment: Thanks, @tanaike, thanks a lot. Interesting, what logics stands behind these limitations. I've added your report to my answer. Feel free to add any details needed